# Linear Hypothesis Tests with unstandardized and standardized variables: Why are the results different?

Tags: r, regression, hypothesis-testing, standardization

I am using the longley economic data in a multiple regression. My full model (`model_transformed`) is $\text{Employment} = \beta_1\text{armed forces} + \beta_2\text{population} + \beta_3\text{gnp}$. I also have a model with standardized variables (`model_scaled`). I want to test the hypothesis that:

$H_0$ : $\beta_1\text{armed forces} + \beta_2\text{population} = 0. $  vs.

$H_a$ : $\beta_1\text{armed forces} + \beta_2\text{population} \ne 0$

I am using the `linearHypothesis()` command in R from the `car` package to carry out this test. I get two radically different $p$-values when I use standardized and unstandardized variables. I know that scaling (standardization) the original variables makes them more 'comparable' -- should I trust the significant result using the standardized variables?

Test Outputs:

[image]

Original Variable Scale:

[image]

Coefficients for the Scaled and Unscaled Models:

[image]

Comment: How is the scaling done, standardization?

Comment: standardized - mean 0, unit variance.

Comment: I find the term "$\beta_1\text{armed forces} + \beta_2\text{population} = 0$" a bit strange. What do you mean by that? $\beta_1$ and $\beta_2$ are fixed. But 'armed forces' and 'population' are variables with error so you won't get this sum to zero.

Comment: Sorry! I just meant that the Beta coefficients themselves are equal to zero. I provided the name of the variable they're associated with as a reference only, but I'm just testing that the coefficients could zero out (ie,  trying to compare magnitude of effect)